# Intuition why $ L= \{\langle M \rangle| \ L(M)=\Sigma ^* \}\notin RE $

Tags: computability, turing-machines, undecidability

I know how to prove it by reduction, but I couldn't find an explanation why it is true.

$\langle M \rangle$ represents the encoding of a turing machine $M$.

Answer (score 2):

The class RE contains all languages $L$ which can be expressed in the form
$$
x \in L \Longleftrightarrow \exists y \, P(x,y),
$$
for some computable predicate $P$.

Your language can be expressed in the following way:
$$
\langle M \rangle \in L \Leftrightarrow \forall x \exists t \, \text{"$M$ halts on $x$ after $t$ steps"}
$$
The quoted predicate is computable. This puts your language in $\Pi_2$, a level on the [arithmetical hierarchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetical_hierarchy). There seems to be no natural way to come up with a simpler expression (less quantifiers), and this is why, intuitively, the language is not r.e. This kind of intuition usually works – write down an expression for your language in the most natural way, and this usually puts it in the correct level of the arithmetical hierarchy.

Your language is in fact $\Pi_2$-complete – every language in $\Pi_2$ can be reduced to it. Indeed, suppose that
$$
x \in L' \Longleftrightarrow \forall y \exists z \, P(x,y,z),
$$
where $P$ is computable. Given $x$, you can construct a Turing machine which on input $y$, goes over all $z$ in parallel, determines the value of each $P(x,y,z)$, and if it ever finds a value of $z$ such that $P(x,y,z)$ is true, it halts. This construction gives a reduction from $L'$ to your language.

Since your language is $\Pi_2$-complete, we know that it is not in $\Sigma_1$ (another name for RE), since the arithmetical hierarchy is strict. This means that there is no way to describe the language using fewer quantifiers (or using $\exists\forall$ rather than $\forall\exists$).

Your language is usually known as TOT, the language of all total Turing machines.

Comment: It is the first time I encounter these concepts but I think I understand the general idea. Is there also a way to explain this using sets notations? Moreover why ∀∃ isn't possible while ∃∀ is? If it isn't about the number of quantifiers what is it about? run time?

Comment: It's a good opportunity for you to get to know logical notation, which is very similar to set notation.

Comment: It's about number of quantifier alternations as well as their type (which quantifier is first). RE and coRE both correspond to one quantifier, but it's a different one.

Comment: Is there a basic source I can use to learn these concepts? I already know these logical notations I was just wondering about the equivalents maybe using alephs and cardinality . In the class I took we only studied about reductions of problems but not about intuitions behind languages that are not recursively enumerable so I am trying to make sense out of it. Thank you for your kind help.